# how to Unit testing eShopOnContainer (IntegrationEventsLog )

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, microservices

This question is specifically related to the eshoponcontainers https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers , and more specifically the IntegrationEvengLog service.

I have the following class that I needed mocked and passed to

```
IEventsContextIntegrationEventService integrationService = NEEDS MOCKING;
var handler = new CreateCoinCommandHandler(context, mapper, integrationService);`
```

I already mocked the `context` with an in-memory dbcontext, mapper is already taken care of, the only param i need is the `integrationService` which also takes in `context` and it has its own dbcontext that needs to be mocked.

Here is my integration service class that I do not know how to mock properly (prefer using a in-memory like i do for `context.

I am sorry for the vagueness but not sure how else to put it

```
public class EventsContextIntegrationEventService: IEventsContextIntegrationEventService
{
    private readonly Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService> integrationEventLogServiceFactory;
    private readonly IEventBus eventBus;
    private readonly EventsContext context;
    private readonly IIntegrationEventLogService eventLogService;

    public EventsContextIntegrationEventService(IEventBus eventBus, EventsContext context,
    Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService> integrationEventLogServiceFactory)
    {
        this.context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        this.integrationEventLogServiceFactory = integrationEventLogServiceFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(integrationEventLogServiceFactory));
        this.eventBus = eventBus ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventBus));
        eventLogService = this.integrationEventLogServiceFactory(this.context.Database.GetDbConnection());
    }

    public async Task PublishThroughEventBusAsync(IntegrationEvent evt)
    {
        try
        {
            await eventLogService.MarkEventAsInProgressAsync(evt.Id);
            eventBus.Publish(evt);
            await eventLogService.MarkEventAsPublishedAsync(evt.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await eventLogService.MarkEventAsFailedAsync(evt.Id);
        }
    }

    public async Task SaveIntegrationEventAndEventContextChangesAsync(IntegrationEvent evt)
    {
        //Use of an EF Core resiliency strategy when using multiple DbContexts within an explicit BeginTransaction():
        //See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency            
        await ResilientTransaction.New(context)
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => {
                // Achieving atomicity between original catalog database operation and the IntegrationEventLog thanks to a local transaction
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                await eventLogService.SaveEventAsync(evt, context.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction());
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want to mock `IEventsContextIntegrationEventService` or `IIntegrationEventLogService`? Either way, what is the challenge that you are facing?

Comment: @dime2lo I need to mock the `IEventsContextIntegrationEventService` which uses `IIntegrationEventLogService` so I guess i would be mocking both, my problem is I dont know where to actually start or how to set this param properly, vague I know, but not sure how else to say it,

Comment: Actually, if you are going to mock `IEventsContextIntegrationEventService` you shouldn´t need to mock `IIntegrationEventLogService`. You should only need to mock `IIntegrationEventLogService` if you were testing `EventsContextIntegrationEventService`(has `IIntegrationEventLogService` dependency).

Comment: @dime2lo I am having trouble mocking `IEventsContextIntegrationEventService` on what that code would look like, i guess my problem is i dont understand it as well as i should to be able to mock it properly.